# POST data empty model

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have View with two dropdownlists first with product category and second depends on selected category list of products. When click save button and ajax redirect to Post AddOrEditPartial in controller my model object has only autogenerated Id and CreateAt. All other data from dropdowns and quantity field are null.I cant find where is the problem. Can somebody help?

```
 public class Warehouse : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Required")]
        public string IdCategory { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Required")]
        public string IdProduct { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity required")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

 public class WarehouseViewModel
    {
        public Warehouse Warehouse { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ProductCategories1 { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

IndexView

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOrEditPartial", "Warehouse", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "formsubmit", OnSuccess = "closePopUp(data)" }))
    {
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Product</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="modbody">
                        @Html.Partial("AddOrEditPartial")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

PartialView

```
@model MyShop.Core.ViewModels.WarehouseViewModel

<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel-default">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">Succes Implement Add/Edit Button</div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="panbody">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Warehouse.Id)

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Warehouse.IdCategory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Warehouse.IdCategory, new SelectList(Model.ProductCategories1, "Category", "Category"), "Please select Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Warehouse.Category, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)new SelectList(ViewBag.Cat, "Category", "Category"), "Please select Category", new { @class = "form-control" })*@

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Warehouse.IdProduct, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Warehouse.IdProduct, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)new SelectList(ViewBag.Prod, "Name", "Name"), "Please Select Product", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Warehouse.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Warehouse.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Warehouse.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSubmit" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Warehouse_IdCategory").change(function () {
            var prodId = $(this).val();
            console.log(prodId);
            //debugger
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProductList", "Warehouse")/' +prodId,
                data: { prodId: prodId },
                contentType: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    //debugger
                    $("#Warehouse_IdProduct").empty();
                    $("#Warehouse_IdProduct").append(response);
                }
            })
        })
    })

</script>
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            WarehouseViewModel whViewModel = new WarehouseViewModel();
            whViewModel.Warehouse = new Warehouse();
            whViewModel.ProductCategories1 = productCategories.Collection();
            whViewModel.Products = contextProduct.Collection();
            return View(whViewModel);
        }
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddOrEditPartial(Warehouse wh)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });

            }
            else
            {
                var data = context.Find(wh.Id);
                if (data != null)
                {
                    data.IdProduct = wh.IdProduct;
                    data.IdCategory = wh.IdCategory;
                    data.Quantity = wh.Quantity;
                    context.Commit();
                }
                else
                {

                    context.Insert(wh);
                    context.Commit();
                }

                return Json(new { success = true });
            }

        }
```

Comment: You are passing only `prodId` to controller action from ajax call. You have to pass `Warehouse` object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change type of your IdCategory & IdProduct to int and it should work.

```
public class Warehouse : BaseEntity
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Required")]
    public int IdCategory { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Required")]
    public int IdProduct { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity required")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But my ProductCategory and Product class Id field is string

Comment: Post your ProductCategory & Product model

Answer (score 0):

@UmairZafar

```
     public class ProductCategory : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

    }
 
    public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        [StringLength(20)]
        [DisplayName("Product Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill product name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Range(0,1000)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }

    }
    
    public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset  CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public BaseEntity()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```